# jQuery ajax get image data from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, png, imagedownload

Here is my Postman test request:

[image]

Here are the headers:

[image]

So here is my AJAX request:

```
var getAvatarData = new FormData();
getAvatarData.append('token', Cookies.get('user_token'));
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: getAvatarData,
    url: AppSettings.userData.photo_path + "s/" + AppSettings.userData.profile.photo,
     contentType: "multipart/form-data",
     processData: false,
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
}).fail(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

So, i always get into the Fail block with Not found.

With those ajax settings:

```
method: "POST",
data: getAvatarData,
url: AppSettings.userData.photo_path + "s/" + AppSettings.userData.profile.photo,
dataType: "json",
mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

I get this also in fail:

[image]

**What i am missing? What is wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

I see you have **dataType** set to **JSON**, if you set this value to JSON, even if you get a 200 ok and the response text is not a well formatted JSON string, you'll land at the error handler.  You can see in your fail object that you got a 200 ok, and the response text contains content.

Try changing your dataType to **image/png** and see what happens.

Also, you could try this bit of code and see if that works for you.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: 'https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg',
  dataType: "image/jpeg",
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: your piece of code does the same as escribed in 2 scenario  = fail with 200

Comment: Did you try changing the dataType in your code?  Your hitting the fail handler because your code is expecting JSON data, which it is not getting.  You could even remove it for testing purposes and jquery will try to guess it.